# Sending attribute table of multiple vector files to excel in QGIS at once?

Tags: qgis, export

I have three different vector files with some data. I want to save as Excel or CSV file. I can do it one by one, but I am wondering if I can do all three in one shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your vectorial shapefiles have the same shape type? i.e either  “Point”, “Line” or “Polygon”? If so, you can merge the shapefiles of your vector data into one shapefile. Here is [an example](https://www.igismap.com/merge-two-shapefile-qgis/).
Then you can export your shapefile as .csv.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin to do so: **Batch Vector Layer Saver**

[image]

Comment: are you referring to the Batch Vector Layer Saver *plugin*?

Comment: You are right. I've named it with the window name. Thanks ¡